Mongoose middleware not saving modifieds values at DB
I have this mongoose schema,
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
...
otp: {
        type: Number,
},
...

I would before save the otp I would like to hash it, I'm using the following middleware, however it keeps saving the raw otp instead of the hashed one, what could I do to make it hash before save?
The middleware is being called and running, just doesnt save the raw password instead of the hashed one.
userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
    // Only run this function if password was actually modified
    if (!this.isModified('otp') || !this.otp) return next();

    this.otp = await bcrypt.hashSync(this.otp.toString(), 12);

    next();
});


You have defined otp as a Number so you won't be able to save a String hash. Were you aware of that?
